# Python: Recursion returning None value

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I am trying to write a program that finds happy numbers:
[more info here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)
This is not a school assignment, but I'm just trying to practice my Python 2.7.
Basically, recursion is a vital part of this because I have to keep squaring every digit.
In my code, I use recursion to keep running it, I have a base case, and it works, but for some reason, even though I call the function, no recursion occurs.
It just returns the digits squares for the first number, which is a bug test, and it returns None, then it stops running.
What's the problem?

```
num = raw_input('Pick a positive integer that you want to check for a happy number')
def happyn(number,second,third,fourth):
  if len(number) == 2:
    go = int(number[0])**2 + int(number[1])**2
  elif len(number) == 3:
    go = int(number[0])**2 + int(number[1])**2 + int(number[2])**2
  elif len(number) == 4:
    go = int(number[0])**2 + int(number[1])**2 + int(number[2])**2 +    int(number[2]**2)

  if len(number) == 1 and int(number) == 1 or int(number) == 7:
    return True
  elif len(number) == 1:
    return False
  else:
    print go
    go = str(go)
    go1 = go[0]
    print go1
    if len(go) == 1:
      go1 = go[0]
      happyn(go1,0,0,0)
    elif len(go) == 2:
      go1 = go[0]
      go2 = go[1]
      happyn(go1,go2,0,0)
    elif len(go) == 3:
      go1 = go[0]
      go2 = go[1]
      go3 = go[2]
      happyn(go1,go2,go3,0)
    elif len(go) == 4:
      go1 = go[0]
      go2 = go[1]
      go3 = go[2]
      go4 = go[4]
      happyn(go1,go2,go3,go4)


print happyn(num,0,0,0)
```

Comment: `go = int(number[0])**2 + int(number[1])**2 + int(number[2])**2 +    int(number[2]**2)` looks like a bug. use `go = sum(int(x)**2 for x in number)` to replace all those cases

Answer (score 9):

All the possible execution branches must *return* something, otherwise the recursion won't work. For example, this is wrong:

```
happyn(go1,0,0,0)
```

If nothing is explicitly returned, the function will return `None`. Therefore, the correct way is:

```
return happyn(go1,0,0,0)
```

The same goes for all the other exit points in your function.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not returning the result of your recursive calls, ie `return happyn(go1, 0, 0, 0)`. In Python, any function that ends without a `return` statement implicitly returns `None`.
2. This is not really a good place to use recursion; a simple `while` loop would suit better.

   ```
   def sum_sq(i):
       total = 0
       while i:
           total += (i % 10) ** 2
           i //= 10
       return total

   def is_happy(i):
       while i >= 10:
           i = sum_sq(i)
       return i in (1, 7)

   def main():
       i = int(raw_input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
       if is_happy(i):
           print("{} is a happy number.".format(i))
       else:
           print("{} is an unhappy number.".format(i))

   if __name__=="__main__":
       main()
   ```